# HISTTIMEFORMAT change is not working at all

Tags: bash, zsh, kali-linux, command-history

I'm trying to put a timestamp to history command

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T '
```

, but commands (both old and new) recorded in history are not showing timestamps.

Output of

```
history | tail
```

```
  445  exoirt HISTTIMEFORMAT='F% T%'
  446  export HISTTIMEFORMAT='F% T%'
  447  history
  448  history | tail
  449  ls
  450  cd
  451  ls
  452  cd
  453  ls
  454  cd
```

I expected some datetime information between the number and the column.  [like here (visible in the below snipped too)](https://linux.101hacks.com/command-line-history/display-timestamp-using-histtimeformat/)

```
       1  2008-08-05 19:02:39 service network restart
       2  2008-08-05 19:02:39 exit
       3  2008-08-05 19:02:39 id
       4  2008-08-05 19:02:39 cat /etc/redhat-release
```

Ouput of

```
type history
```

is

```
history is an alias for history 0
```

I tried to insert the variable in ~/.bashrc file, but again it did not work.

**Edit:**
I am running Kali linux. I tried rebooting my system and resetting my history size and data.
**Edit #2:**
Output of

```
echo $ZSH_VERSION
```

```
5.8
```

Output of

```
echo $SHELL
```

```
/usr/bin/zsh
```

Comment: it's true that older entries won't take timestamp, but for new entries, AFAIK you need to flush out your `.bash_history` content first to get ride of old entries

Comment: How are you checking this? If your `history` is aliased to `history 0`, then it shouldn't even have any output.

Comment: I cleared bash history file and its still not working.
Both 'type' and 'which' against history is showing its aliased that way.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you mean by "not working". Show us the output of `history | tail` and explain how it is not what you are expecting. The time format will not be visible in the history file.

Comment: Done. By not working I mean its not showing date.

Comment: Did you restart `history` by doing `zzz=$HISTSIZE;HISTSIZE=0;HISTSIZE=$zzz`? Or start a new shell? Or logout/login?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: `history` is an alias for `history 0`, as you show, by default on Kali Linux.  Are you running Kali Linux?  If so, you are actually using the `zsh` shell, not `bash` at all. History formatting is not implemented at all in the same way on `zsh`.  Please update your question with the relevant information.

Comment: Which of the two commands `echo $BASH_VERSION` and `echo $ZSH_VERSION` outputs anything, and what does it output?  Also let us know what `echo $SHELL` outputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on Kali Linux.  The Kali Linux distribution is using `zsh` as its default login shell, not `bash`.

This means that any change you make to `~/.bashrc` would not be seen by the shell you use.  The `zsh` shell is instead using the `~/.zshrc` file for initializations of interactive shell sessions.

Furthermore, the `zsh` shell has no shell variable called `HISTTIMEFORMAT` that does anything in particular. (If you had been using `bash`, you would not have had to `export` this variable, by the way.)  Instead you will have to use the `history` builtin command to view the history in different ways.

However, first you will have to get the shell to store the history information in its extended format, which include timestamps.  You do this with

```bsh
setopt EXTENDED_HISTORY
```

(You can do this in `~/.zshrc` if you want it in all shell sessions that you start).  This shell option is documented in the `zshoptions` manual.

Then, you will have to get rid of the rather unhelpful alias for `history` that the default `~/.zshrc` on Kali Linux sets up, since it stops us from using the `history` command properly.

Either comment out the line

```bsh
alias history="history 0"
```

or add

```bsh
unalias history
```

at the end of the file.

Then, you should be able to see timestamps using

```
history -i
```

See also the documentation for `fc` (`history` is actually the same as `fc -l`) in the `zshbuiltins` manual for how to format the output of `history` in the format you want.  For example

```
history -t '%F %T'
```

(This happens to be almost exactly the same output format as from `history -i`, but with seconds added.)